# My app does not display in the browser when using React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My main App component does not display in the browser even though no error message is displayed.
Please assist

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {BrowserRouter as Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
    import MasterLayout from './layouts/admin/MasterLayout';

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
         
               <Routes>
               
               <Route path="/admin/dashboard" component = {MasterLayout} />

               
           </Routes>
         
        
        
         
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

I don't understand why the App main component does not render on my webpage. There are no errors, but the web page is empty. Please assist me.

Comment: What is the version of `react-router-dom` you are using ?

Comment: I using  version v6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code, you are not displaying any UI for main page or base router `"localhost:3000/"`, only displaying in the `"localhost:3000/admin/dashboard"`

```
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
               <Routes>
               <Route path="/admin/dashboard" component = {MasterLayout} />
           </Routes>
        </div>
     )
   }
```

Comment: Yes but the dashboard has content in it that should have rendered. Infact I was following an online video . Only difference in my code and his was he used BrowserRouter and Switch from react-router-dom but it is now deprecated so could not use it .

Comment: Since I'm also missed the component attribute. Glad that other developers figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In version 6 for `react-router-dom`, it should be `element` instead of `component`, and you should call the component (`<MasterLayout/>`), like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import MasterLayout from './layouts/admin/MasterLayout';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App"> 
       <Routes> 
           <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element = {<MasterLayout/>} /> 
       </Routes>  
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MasterLayout from './layouts/admin/MasterLayout';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element = {<MasterLayout/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

try this if it's not working check your imported MasterLayout

Comment: Awesome, awesome worked like magic! Thank you a billion Janith, right?

Comment: i think error is<Route path="/admin/dashboard" element = {<MasterLayout/>} /> line .